# How did Toshinou Kyouko's personality change?

Tags: yuru-yuri

In episode 11 of the first season of the anime, there was a flashback where it was shown that little Toshinou Kyouko was nothing like the current Toshinou Kyouko — she was quiet, shy and even had less presence than Akaza Akari. Yet, the current Toshinou Kyouko is nothing like that.

What happened between the time when she was shown as a quiet and shy little girl and the current her? Has the author ever being asked about this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe that because Kyouko was being bullied, she became shy and wary of people and her true personality was being suppressed.

[image]

Once Akari came to stop the bullying, Kyouko would have been able to have more confidence in herself, letting her express herself more, becoming the Kyouko we know and love today.

As for an official statement, I can't seem to find one on the author's Twitter account, or from googling - but I'm fairly certain it would be a similar answer to the one above.

Comment: I love it when the user/character answers the question pertaining about himself/herself lol.

Comment: "Once Akari came to stop the bullying". Hahaha, you won't stop teasing her outside the series either, huh? Poor Akari!  xD